# C# adding image property to controlbox

Tags: c#

My userControl1.cs contains a text box and a picture box
how do I add a property to my class to allow it to get a picture from a url string

this is what i have so far

```
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public override string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return textBox1.Text;
        }

        set
        {
            textBox1.Text = value;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you add the property,

```
public Image PictureFromWeb  { get; set;}
```

but there is a better way

The inbuilt [PictureBox.Load(string URL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f6ak7was.aspx)  Method "sets the ImageLocation to the specified URL and displays the image indicated." (Since .NetFramework 2) 

 Quoted from [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071025/load-an-image-from-a-url-into-a-picturebox) -- Upvote his answer

Comment: so im trying to have the picture box in the user control get url and convert it into a pic, Im using userControl11.UserPicture = tweet.Creator.DownloadProfileImage(token); DownloadProfileImage retrieves the url string. I changed FamilyPicture to UserPicture