# Bind a PictureBox with a string of a url for LoadAsync

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding, picturebox

Is there a way to bind a PictureBox to a string so that when the string will change, it will call `LoadAsync()` with the url in the string and load an image?

Currently this is what I have in the auto generated code.

```
this.itemImagePictureBox.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Image", this.MySource, "ItemImage", true));
```

What I want instead is:

```
this.itemImagePictureBox.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("String", this.MySource, "ImageUrl", true));
```

`MySource` has a property for url string, and I also tried to make it have a field of an `Image`, but a `Bitmap` for example doesn't have a load async feature so I still can't use the url string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the [`WaitOnLoad`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.waitonload(v=vs.110).aspx) property is `false` (default), thus enabling asynchronous image load, and then bind to [`ImageLocation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.imagelocation(v=vs.110).aspx) property:

```
this.itemImagePictureBox.WaitOnLoad = false;
this.itemImagePictureBox.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding(
    "ImageLocation", this.MySource, "ImageUrl", true));
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be databinding? Why not:

```
MyImage = new Bitmap(fileToDisplay);
itemImagePictureBox.Image = (Image) MyImage ;
await itemImagePictureBox.LoadAsync();
itemImagePictureBox.Refresh();
```

Or, if the image is a URL:

[Load an image from a url into a PictureBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071025/load-an-image-from-a-url-into-a-picturebox)