# Display images in multiple picture boxes from web

Tags: c#

I am working on Online School Report Card. I want to show all the scanned Answer sheets to the students in form of picture boxes. One image in one picture box is displaying. I want to show all scanned pictures in multiple picture box (max 16) in one window form in C#.

Made 16 picture boxes for maximum 16 scanned answer sheets of student. On selecting class and ID, pictures are showing in pictures boxes.

```
urlARC_PIC = BMS.Class.urlARC + cboSTU_CLS.Text + "/" + cboSTU_ID.Text + "/" + lblPG0.Text + ".jpg";

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlARC_PIC);

request.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(user, pass, domain);

request.UserAgent = "Code Sample Web Client";

using (var response = request.GetResponse())

using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())

{ picPG0.Image = Bitmap.FromStream(stream); }
```

If number of scanned pics are 13, then only 13 picture boxes should be filled on dropdown of Combo box of Stu_ID. On click of save button, only modified picture box should be updated in school website.

Comment: With this code... Are you able to display one image?

Comment: There no question here, only a statement of intent

Comment: Yes, one image is showing without any error

Comment: @ Michael , Here is my question :- If number of scanned pics are 13, then only 13 picture boxes should be filled on dropdown of Combo box of Stu_ID. On click of save button, only modified picture box should be updated in school website.

c#

Comment: Then you need to call the service 13 times and load the images in individual imageboxes....

Comment: You can also assign service URL directly to each of the picture box.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071025/load-an-image-from-a-url-into-a-picturebox you don't need to use `HttpWebRequest`...